# Collection fetch join

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, architecture

Suppose I have an JPA entity and a query:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ChildEntity> children = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>();
}


public List<MyEntity> fetchAll() {
    return em.createQuery("select distinct e from MyEntity e join fetch e.children")
            .getResultList();
}
```

Without **distinct** keyword it will do a cross-product of MyEntity and e.children.

**Is it considered a good practice to use both distinct and join fetch to avoid N+1 Select problem with collections? Does it have side-effects?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use "SELECT DISTINCT" because is being executed a cartesian product between MyEntity and children.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt an inner join do the trick?

```
public List<MyEntity> fetchAll() {
    return em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e inner join fetch e.children")
            .getResultList();
}
```

Comment: No, it has the same result. Suppose I have 2 MyEntities with 2 children each. This query returns 4 MyEntities, but I want only 2.